# RhinoMock : How to Stub and Return a method with complex object as parameter

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, stub

I highly appreciate anyone can help me in below-mentioned issue:
I've been using RhinoMock in Unit Test.
I define my mock object in such manner, with sessionToken is string-typed:

```
mockRepository.Stub(repository => repository.FindById(sessionToken)).Return(new DeviceTypeRepository().NewTable(false));
```

It's ok for the code section when calling **FindById()** to return the **valid** new new DeviceTypeRepository().NewTable(false);

However, when include a complex parameter as object, such as a DataTable, into the Stub as below:

```
mockRepository.Stub(repository => repository.Find(sessionToken, dataTable)).Return(new DeviceTypeRepository().NewTable(false));
```

Then the code section in which **Find()** is invoked, it does **NOT** return expected new DeviceTypeRepository().NewTable(false).
Notice that input value of parameter dataTable is the same in both Stub and in Find() invocation.

Hence, my question is:
How could I implement such parameter (DataTable typed and more generally) into Stub initialization using RhinoMock ? I'd be grateful to any advice and approach.
Thanks

Comment: Is `dataTable`'s _value_ or _reference_ the same in both `Stub()` and `Find()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it doesn't return what you'd expect, then the parameters between the stub call and the actual call don't match. Let's say you have something like this:

```cs
// Set expectations
var someDataTable = new DataTable(columns, raws);
mockRepository
   .Stub(repository => repository.Find(sessionToken, dataTable))
   .Return(new DeviceTypeRepository().NewTable(false));

// Actual test
var anotherDataTable = new DataTable(columns, raws);
yourTestObject.DoSomethingThatLooksForTheDataTable(repository);
```

The thing here that even though the `someDataTable` and `anotherDataTable` have the exact same content, they're not the same object and when RhinoMocks compare the stub call to the actual call the parameters don't match. What you can do is use constraints:

```cs
mockRepository
   .Stub(repository => repository.Find(
      Arg<SessionID>.Matches(y => y.ID == 2),
      Arg<DataTable>.Matches(x => x.Columns == columns && x.Raws == raws)
   ))
   .Return(true);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to use Contraints of RhinoMock ?
Something alike: 
mockRepository.Stub(repository => repository.Find(..., ...)).Contraints(Is.EqualTo(x), ...)

Answer (score 9):

I believe the problem is not in a complex datatype but rather in the expectations you've set.

As a first attempt to fix it, add `IgnoreArguments()` before the `Return`. It could be that `DataTable` you've specified in expectation differs from the actually-passed-in `DataTable` instance so expectations won't pass:

```cs
...Stub(...).IgnoreArguments().Return();
```

If not helped you can debug it manually using WhenCalled():

```cs
...Stub(...).IgnoreArguments().WhenCalled(
    mi => 
    {
        var token = mi.Arguments[0] as TokenDataType;
        var dataTable = mi.Arguments[1] as DataTable;
    }).Return();
```

If that doesn't help, try to add `Repeat().Any()` after the `Return()` and see whether it works. I am supposing that if the method was called a few times, you may have missed the first return value, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I liked the WhenCalled usage. However, with Stub you wouldn't need to add Repeat().Any(), it's the default behavior.

Comment: @Amittai Shapira : good point, thanks, any reference to documentation? I mostly using Mock and for mock it does not repeat by default

Comment: Thank you for asking for evidence. I was wrong :-( the behavior of mocks and stubs in this case is similar, the default is Repeat().Once(): http://groups.google.com/group/rhinomocks/browse_thread/thread/03aff4992b5607cb

Comment: I had the same issue and by adding .IgnoreArguments().Return it sorted me out. Thanks!!